# Why I can't install plugins?

Tags: qgis, repository

I have a PC windows7 
and my QGIS version is 2.14
the QGIS official plugin repository is unavailable!
how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: This will not solved your problem but the new Qgis LTR is 2.18, it's preferable to update. Do you have a proxy ? can you share some screenshot please

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: You may be trapped behind a proxy, or other internet restrictions.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. However I have tried using https but still cannot connected to the repository. It might be changed for the sites. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use this source: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

It is the same, but using the `https` protocol.

[image]