# QGIS 3.4.1 Extensions Repository not available

Tags: qgis, installation, error, extensions

In my QGIS 3.4.1 installation (Windows 10) the extensions repository says `"unavailable"`, like in this older post: [Why I can't install plugins?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263912/why-i-cant-install-plugins).

I already added the repository with `"HTTP"` instead of `"HTTPS"`, but it shows the same error.

I changed nothing on my network installation, so a proxy-problem should not be the reason.

In my older QGIS 2.18.16 installation, the repository works just fine.

Maybe anyone has a suggestion how to fix the problem?

Comment: You could have provided some pictures about problem u have.

Comment: Don`t want to use unnecessary space, the visual description can bee seen in the link in my original post - it's exactly the same (but in german language :-)) ;-)

Comment: Are you able to access the address with a web browser? Can you ping the adress?

Comment: Same issue here - just installed 3.4.1 day before yesterday and haven't been able to access plugins repository since.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150695)

Comment: As andreas said, can you open this link from your browser? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

Comment: yes, I can open it without any trouble in any browser... https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=3.4

Comment: ...still no solution found...